# php if statement inside a css class

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

When I try to return JSON response from Laravel `controller`, I try to use if statement inside the class but I get no error but nothing works I try this:

```
foreach($active_users as $user) {
    $output.='<tr>'.
        '<td>'.
            '<h2><a>'
                .$user->name.
            '</a>'.'</h2>'.
        '</td>'.
        '<td>'.$user->created_at.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$user->classe->classe_name.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$user->ville.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$user->phone_number.'</td>'.
        '<td> <span class=' ."<?php if($user->active == 'active') { echo 'bg-primary-light' }
                     ?>" .'</span>'.
        '</td>'.
    '</tr>';
    return Response($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex and long HTML template, it's recommended to use BladeTemplate since PHP concatenation with dot notation is such a pain in the back. It's easier to handle logic and loops in Blade template. Then in the controller just

```
return view('view.example')->render();
```

I've tried your controller, final result is the same, less hassle and more managable

Comment: Pham but i'm making this search on keyup event  and i return just a part of view not all all page how i can render a html table part

Comment: @moussa Exactly! The render() helper will return the view as HTML without reloading the page. And the view that is being returned ONLY contains "part" that need to be updated. Assuming you made request via AJAX, on "success" event, and from then, it's the same: display the returned HTML. 
If you haven't had any idea of what I just described, here are the steps:
1. Create a NEW view, containing <tr> element
2. In the controller that handle request: replace from `foreach`: `return view('view.example', compact('active_users'))->render();`
3. In the view: use Blade syntax like usual: @foreach

Comment: In case you want to `return` for every $user, place the foreach loop in the controller instead of the view. So `foreach($active_users as $user){ return view('view.example', compact('user'))->render(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator instead of a full if else block inside the string and no need for `<PHP>` and `echo` inside the string quotes from the controller class.

Change this line

```
'<td> <span class=' ."<?php if($user->active == 'active') { echo 'bg-primary-light' }
                 ?>" .'</span>'.

                '</td>'
```

to like this

```
'<td> <span class="' .$user->active == "active"?"bg-primary-light":"".'"></span></td>'
```

Try to use like this and append to the code using ajax.

Comment: You're missing the closing '>' in the span, as op does too

Comment: @moussa try to print a dd($user->active); before this string operations start and please check is it returning "active"

Comment: @N69S idea conveyed. he has to find out the way to include it in his code.

Comment: @Unni k where i should put > i try different places it seems not working can you modify answer please  '<td> <span class="' .$user->active == 'active'?'bg-primary-light':''.'>"</span></td>'. i try this

Comment: @moussa it's already edited, you can also copy/paste the code from my answer. it should work too

Comment: dd($user->active) return en attente from my database

Comment: @moussa answer modified by N69S . You have to verify $user->active == 'active'. Please check modified answer of mine

Comment: @UnniKS it return the name of classe bg-primary-light instead of using it as classe

Comment: I'm not getting your point. Please elaborate on your question using all these findings as screenshot.

Comment: @UnniKS how can i add screenshot

Comment: @UnniKS i get bg-primary-light in response

Answer (score 0):

your delimiters are wrongly set for the html to be valid

```
'<td> <span class="' .($user->active == 'active')?'bg-primary-light':''.'">'.
'</span>'.
```